# Scala recursive method to search in a list

Tags: list, algorithm, scala, recursion

I am trying to make a recursive function in scala to look in a list that includes scores of players so that I can take the top 3 and show it on the screen.

The List:

```
val values = List(score_player1, score_player2, score_player3, score_player4, score_player5)
```

Comment: What have you tried, why it didn't work? Did you get some compilation error? Did you get some runtime error? Did you get a wrong result? Does it have to be recursive? Does it have to be tail-recursive? Is score an **Int** or a **Double** or it may be any kind of number?

Comment: Currently there is one manual player (player 1 standard with the rest being bots), so I just look at the index of player 1 and if it is the maximum I show him as the winner. I am just trying to experiment bij using tail recursion, but I am not quite sure how to use it on a list in scala. The score of the players are Ints.

Comment: Are you able to implement the maximum using recursion? If so, paste that code, if not, try to do that at least. Think in the base case and in the recursive case. Also, remember an empty list doesn't have a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala List you have three methods for applying sort algorithms:

```
def sortBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): C

def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: Ordering[B]): C

def sortWith(lt: (A, A) => Boolean): C
```

If your score_player is a numerical type, just:

```
list.sortBy(_).take(3) 
 // or
list.sortBy(-_).take(3)
```

You don´t need to code an explicit recursion method, indeed, List methods do recursion in order to provide different functions that they provide.

Comment: _"indeed, List methods do recursion in order to provide different functions that they provide"_, actually, that is false, the std implementation of list uses a while loop and mutability in order to be very efficient.  Also, it seems OP is doing some homework, thus probably the use of standard methods is prohibited and it has to do the recursion. Finally, as OP don't show any effort to solve the problem, his/her question shouldn't be answered.

Comment: I know. There are fold implementations that work in that way. But there are some that are implemented using tail recursion like lengthCompare.

Comment: As far as I can tell only `lengthCompare` is implemented like that, check the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L79). Anyways, that isn't really the point.